# Firebase.auth Example Not Working

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I'm trying to add very basic authentication for my test Firebase site using this example:

```
 myDB.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).catch(function (error) {
        // stuff
  }
```

I get an error 'Firebase.auth failed: Was called with 0 arguments. Expects at least 1.'

myDB is a reference like :  new Firebase('https://myDB.firebaseio.com');

I am using version 2.4.2."https://cdn.firebase.com/js/client/2.4.2/firebase.js">

How can I get this simple example working?

Comment: what is mydb equal to?

Comment: myDB is a reference to:  new Firebase('https://myDB.firebaseio.com'); - sorry, had a typo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using a very old Firebase version, please update to the latest version:

```
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/4.12.0/firebase.js"></script>
```

more info here:

https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/js

then configure the firebase project and initialize it:

```
var config = {
apiKey: "<API_KEY>",
authDomain: "<PROJECT_ID>.firebaseapp.com",
databaseURL: "https://<DATABASE_NAME>.firebaseio.com",
storageBucket: "<BUCKET>.appspot.com",
messagingSenderId: "<SENDER_ID>",
 };
 firebase.initializeApp(config);
```

then you can use `firebase.auth()`:

https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.auth

and use the sign in method:

```
firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).catch(function(error) {
  // Handle Errors here.
var errorCode = error.code;
var errorMessage = error.message;
 });
```

Also before Sign in you need to use `createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)` to authenticate the account.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/start